# MySQL RGB Comparison error - Commands out of sync

Tags: mysql, sql, rgb

I am trying to order a list of colours in based on their distance from a sample.
The formula is:

> d = sqrt( (sR-R)^2 - (sG-G)^2 - (sB-B)^2 )

The sample I am testing with is: sRGB(255,0,0).

This is my code:

```
    SELECT color.id, color.red, color.green, color.blue, brand.name, 
    SQRT(POW((255-color.red),2)+POW((0-color.green),2)+POW((0-color.blue),2)) AS d
    FROM color, brand 
    WHERE color.brand = brand.id 
    ORDER BY d
    LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

I keep getting the error:

> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Not sure what is happening.

Extra Info:

- MySQL 5.6.22
- Running the code in phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.7

Comment: So this works fine in the MySQL CLI?

Comment: @Strawberry it is on an external host, I only have ftp and phpMyAdmin access. All I know is it is not working in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I think this is a problem with the host

Comment: @Strawberry do you know of any way I can confirm this, or go about fixing it?

Comment: Well, you can test it locally, or on sqlfiddle. If it works, then you know.

Comment: @Strawberry,Ty - I did not know sqlfiddle existed.
I get a different error on sqlfiddle.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84bf9/2
error:
Data truncation: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(0 - `db_2_84bf9`.`color`.`green`)': SELECT color.red, color.green, color.blue, brand.name, SQRT(POW((255-color.red),2)+POW((0-color.green),2)+POW((0-color.blue),2)) AS d FROM color, brand WHERE color.brand = brand.id ORDER BY d LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

Comment: The bigint declaration differs from one table to the other, but that's not the whole story. Hm, not sure, but this seems to work... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/557be6/1

Comment: @Strawberry, Yes that works thanks, Still get the "#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" I will contact my host.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of "Data truncation: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range"

... POW(0-CAST(color.green AS SIGNED), 2) ...

"#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" comes from an improperly constructed Stored Procedure.  Let's see the whole SP.

Comment: Sorry might be a noob question but what is the "SP"?

Comment: SP = Stored Procedure.  If you did not create a SP, then the mystery thickens.  Perhaps phpmyadmin is somehow wrapping your query in a SP??